# Deleting Team Project in Azure DevOps ends in strange folders in Sourcecode Explorer of VS

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Following Azure DevOps documentation, I have deleted a number of projects. The project is removed from the online view but strange folders now appear in VS 2017 source control explorer. These folders contain source code from the deleted projects.

[image: screenshot sourcecode explorer]

I tried to delete and resync my workspace but the unwanted folders synced again. Can anyone who has seen this behavior advise how i can get rid of them?

br Nico

Comment: I have the same problem for many months now, and it's a true pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

It seems like this is not a new issue. I am able to reproduce this with TFVC projects only. Take a look at [this post](https://intovsts.net/2009/11/25/deleted-team-projects-still-visible-in-source-control-explorer/) about how to remove "deleted" team projects. Hopefully that gets you moving in the right direction.

If all else fails... use Git :)

---

Original:

It seems to me like VS is holding onto some information about the remote and which projects it expects to be there.
You may simply need to refresh the connection in VS.

[image]
[image]

If the refresh still shows the deleted projects, try removing the server connection completely, and adding it fresh.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry didn´t solve the problem. I tried to setup the source control on a complete different machine logon with my account and setup the workspace and it´s the same picture.